# What is this message about new codec from www.onnify.com?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

Recently, when I start Google Chrome browser, a window pops up (sorry, I did not save a screenshot), saying something like *new codec available from [www.onnify.com](http://www.onnify.com/)*.

What exactly is the significance of this? A spam? A Malware? Or a Trozan Horse?

When I visit  [the mentioned site](http://www.onnify.com/), I find something in the line of codecs and faster PC experience.

As we find [at this](http://www.scamvoid.com/check/onnify.com) site, this site has a bad reputation.

Do you think you can put light on the issue? To begin with, how do I remove the pop up message?

Comment: check your extensions on Chrome menu -> Tools -> Extensions

Comment: @Sathya Checked. All I have are, ESPN Cricinfo 1.8.4.1, Google Docs 0.5, Markdown Here 2.9.4 
and Youtube Video Downloader. Could any of these be responsible?

Comment: they seem fine, how about Chrome menu -> settings -> under On startup, is it set to _Open a specific page or set of pages._?

Comment: @Sathya No, this is set to `Continue where I left off`.

Answer (score 2):

your browser has been hijacked. in addition to changing your page back (http://chrome.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/clean-up-your-hijacked-settings.html) you should also peruse your add/remove programs list for things you don't recognise.

these things often manifest themselves in the form of programs pretending to be something else, or using names like "new offers toolbar". be vigilant. install malwarebytes' anti-malware if you don't trust yourself.